# how do I sum a table column?

Tags: 7, search

Is there a  way to sum a numeric value and display it from a field column data in a table view format using search api? I have a DB server (not solr). I need facets.

I've tried the following methods:

1.- search api node index views has no "aggregation settings" (not possible here).

2.- Views calc module (goes out of memory).

3.- Views Aggregator Plus module, "it works", but always result is equal to zero.

I'm run out of posible sulutions, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module does the job, https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize, also I'm using a bootstrap sub-theme and all modules above mensioned break css, and this module does not.